# How to button clicked using playwright testing framework?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, nuxt.js, playwright

Currently , i am doing an end to end testing in my nuxt project. I want to test the frontend of my project to ensure the UI is presentable and clickable. However , I am facing a problem for my button. It felt like button is not clicked. I am pretty sure the css selector for my button is correctly defined as shown in here

[image: Button Screenshot]

The screenshot shows that the button is hovered over or partially clicked. Is there any way to solve this issue ?

`page.spec.ts`

```js
import { resolve, join } from 'path'
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test'

const ROOT_PATH = resolve(__dirname, '..', 'screenshots')

test('job board test', async ({ page, baseURL }) => {
  await page.goto(baseURL + '/') // <-- Nuxt app is running and route '/' is showing.
  const html = await page.innerHTML('body')
  console.log(html)
  await expect(page.locator('h2').locator('text= meow')).toBeVisible()
  await page.fill('text=User name', 'jeff');
  await page.fill('text= Password', 'jeff');

  await page.locator('.v-btn').click(); // button clicked

  // Step 1 - Is Homepage working
  await page.screenshot({ path: join(ROOT_PATH, 'detail.png') })

})
```

Comment: There is no error it seems so it would be hard for anyone to help you out. would you mind try using trace and view or provide the trace ?

You can enable it in your global config as details provided here - https://playwright.dev/docs/trace-viewer#recording-a-trace

Keep it `on` instead of `on-first-retry`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try force clicking the button. Setting `force` to `true` will bypass the actionability check.

```js
 await page.locator('.v-btn').click({force: true});
```